# help with PHP pagination

Tags: php, mysql, html, pagination

hello guys im using this second part of pagination script to show pagination;

```
<?
if ($pageno == 1) {
   echo "<li class='previous-off'>«« İlk Sayfa</li> <li class='previous-off'>« Önceki Sayfa</li> ";
} else {
   echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=1'>«« İlk Sayfa</a></li> ";
   $prevpage = $pageno-1;
   echo "<li> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$prevpage'>« Önceki Sayfa</a> </li>";
} // if
echo " <li class='active'>$pageno</li>";
if ($pageno == $lastpage) {
   echo " <li class='previous-off'>«« Sonraki</li> <li class='previous-off'>« Son Sayfa</li> ";
} else {
   $nextpage = $pageno+1;
   echo " <li class='next'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$nextpage'>Sonraki »</a></li> ";
   echo " <li class='next'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$lastpage'>Son Sayfa »»</a></li> ";
} // if
?>
```

like you see here: `echo " <li class='active'>$pageno</li>";` i only can show first, prev, active page, next, last page..

my question is: i want to show more pages near active page.. how can i do this?

i mean pagination style is now like:

> FIRST PREV 1 NEXT LAST

i want

> FIRST PREV 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 NEXT LAST

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a loop which loops from the first to the last page numbers:

```
for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $amount_of_pages; $page_number++)
    if($page_number == $pageno)
        echo " <li class='active'>$page_number (active)</li>";
    else
        echo " <li class='active'><a href="...">$page_number</a></li>";
```

To let this work you'd need to find the maximum amount of items and divide it with the amount of items on a page:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$amount_of_items = $row[0];
$amount_of_pages = $amount_of_items / 10; // 10 items on a page
```

Of course you need to add some checks and stuff, this only shows the basic principles.

Comment: i do this: for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $lastpage; $page_number++)
    echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$page_number'>$page_number</a></li>"; this works. but it showing like FIRST PREV 1(active) 1 2 3 NEXT LAST

Comment: You can use some if statement to check if `$page_number` is equal to `$pageno`, in order to be able to show some indication/remove the link/etc. I have updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: well thank you i let it work! for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $lastpage; $page_number++)
echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$page_number'>$page_number</a></li>"; this code is works but "active li style" is not working. all page numbers are showing standard <li>. how i can set <li class="active"> to current page and others normal?

Comment: kkkkk my mistake sorry lol. it works very very fine! thank you so much veger.. now im gonna sent last version of script. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Between the part which displays the previous page links and the part which displays the next page links, you need a loop between 1 and total pages.

```
<?php
$currentPage = 3;
$totalPages = 10;
?>

<a href="">First page</a>
<a href="">Prev page</a>

<?php
for ($i = 0; < $totalPages; $i++) {
    printf('<a href="%s?page=%d" class="%s">Page %d</a>', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $i, ($i == $currentPage ? 'active' : ''), $i);
}
?>

<a href="">Next page</a>
<a href="">Last page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
if ($pageno == 1) {
   echo "<li class='previous-off'>«« İlk Sayfa</li> <li class='previous-off'>« Önceki Sayfa</li> ";
} else {
   echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=1'>«« İlk Sayfa</a></li> ";
   $prevpage = $pageno-1;
   echo "<li> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$prevpage'>« Önceki Sayfa</a> </li>";
} // if
for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $lastpage; $page_number++)
if($page_number == $pageno) {
echo "<li class='active'>$pageno</li>";
}
else {
echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$page_number'>$page_number</a></li>";
}

if ($pageno == $lastpage) {
   echo " <li class='previous-off'>«« Sonraki</li> <li class='previous-off'>« Son Sayfa</li> ";
} else {
   $nextpage = $pageno+1;
   echo " <li class='next'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$nextpage'>Sonraki »</a></li> ";
   echo " <li class='next'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?isim=$kid&sayfa=$lastpage'>Son Sayfa »»</a></li> ";
} // if
?>
```

this is fixed version. works fine.